# Importing <div> element as SVGElement

Tags: html, svg, internet-explorer-9

I am importing a string containing a `<div>` element into a SVG document; Even after importing it, it still shows as [object Element] whereas I want to see it as SVGElement (Adobe SVG Viewer does it). Is there a possibility?

Note: I am using IE9!

Thanks
Venkatesh

Comment: I should think you would need to change the tag, perhaps to a <text> type instead? Afaik <div> isn't a valid SVG element. What are you using to do the import: JavaScript? jQuery?

Comment: I am using java script and once imported, I want to use the <div> element in the popup (tooltip)

Comment: That statement probably requires more detail. Do you want to attach a mouseover to a part of your SVG document? If so, I still think it needs to be valid SVG. I've not used it, but suspect that [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) might be useful to you - looks like you can do all sorts of vector goodness, and attach JS events to individual elements.

Comment: We are more inclined towards using the native support from IE9 than using other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `foreignObject` tag of svg, Which enables you to embed html doc. fargments in svg.
I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jE6tg/, which shows it in action.
Click on the "Import div tag to svg" button to copy the `.importee` div into the svg doc.

Comment: It does import but if you check that back, it would still say an element instead of SVGElement.